# how to store user IP in database asp.net?

Tags: c#, database

I want to store user_ip in database when he logs in so I created table for login history
which got the IP as nvarchar(50) then i search and I found this method which returns the IP as string

```
    <i>

public string GetUser_IP()
{
    string VisitorsIPAddr = string.Empty;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null)
    {
        VisitorsIPAddr = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();
    }
    else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.Length != 0)
    {
        VisitorsIPAddr = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
    }
    return VisitorsIPAddr;
}
</i>
```

but it stores the ip like this `::1`
please help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running your application using `localhost`. try to run with IP then it will capture `IP`.

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Request.UserHostName`:

```
var ipAddress = Request.UserHostName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code From [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/293633/how-to-get-system-ip-address-when-user-login-in-cs)

It works even if it is run in the localhost

```
public static string getclientIP()
{
    string result= string.Empty;
    string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
    {
        string[] ipRange = ip.Split(',');
        int le = ipRange.Length - 1;
        result = ipRange[0];
    }
    else
    {
        result = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ::1 IP address means that the web page have been called directly from the server (probably by using localhost domain name).

If you call the web page from an other computer or if you call it using without using the localhost domain name (using your LAN or WAN IP Address) you'll get the IP Address used by the client to access your web page.